# With the Kendo UI Grid, how do you access the filtered and sorted data?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo grid that is sortable and filterable.  When I export I want to export all the data that is currently viewable but not just the current page.

`$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource`  -> seems to be the original list of items unsorted and unfiltered.  In Chrome Developer tools, `_data` and `_pristine` seem to be the same.

There is also the `dataSource.view` but it is only the 10 items visible on the current page.

Is there a way to access the sorted list and/or filtered list?

update:
I have found this answer on the Kendo forums and will see if it helps.
http://www.kendoui.com/forums/framework/data-source/get-filtered-data-from-paged-grid.aspx

Comment: I met the same requirements to export the filtered data as csv, if you managed to get the filtered and sorted data from the grid please share with us, thanks

Comment: Strangely in my system $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource contains  only the records of the current page.  My configuration is MVC and the data is fetched from the server. I suspect that this the difference source.

Answer (score 8):

Here is how you access the filtered data:

```
 var dataSource = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
        var filteredDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            data: dataSource.data(),
            filter: dataSource.filter()
        });

        filteredDataSource.read();
        var data = filteredDataSource.view();
```

And then you can loop through the data:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            result += "<tr>";

            result += "<td>";
            result += data[i].SiteId;
            result += "</td>";

            result += "<td>";
            result += data[i].SiteName;
            result += "</td>";

            result += "</tr>";
  }
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it does not work for me. The dataSource contains only the records that are displayed on the current page. That is, if I have 480 records displayed in 48 pages of 10 each, I get only the 10 records that are displayed on the current page.

Comment: Would you post code to show your grid initialization.

Comment: You could also use this on the `filter` event added during grid initialization (It passes the filters as an argument in the function). But instead of using `filter: dataSource.filter()` you'd use `filter: arg.filter` to set it to the currently selected filters.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the answers out there apply to the Kendo Grid when just looking at local data in memory.  If you are using remote data (i.e. your grid is bound to an ODATA source for example) - you will need to iterate through all the pages to get the filtered data.

However, doing this was not as straight forward as I thought.

I came up with the following:

```
      var filteredRows = [];

      function getResults() {

        var dataSource = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
        var filters = dataSource.filter();
        var allData = dataSource.data();
        var query = new kendo.data.Query(allData);
        var data = query.filter(filters).data;            

        var totalRowCount = parseInt(dataSource.total().toString());
        var totalPages = Math.ceil(totalRowCount / dataSource.pageSize());

        PageTraverser(dataSource, 1, totalPages, filters, function () {
                        $('#pResults').text('Got ' + filteredRows.length + ' rows of filtered data.');              
        });            
      }

      function PageTraverser(dataSource, targetPage, totalPages, filters, completionFunction) {

        dataSource.query({
          page: targetPage,
          pageSize: 20,
          filter: filters
        }).then(function () {
          var view = dataSource.view();
          for (var viewItemId = 0; viewItemId < view.length; viewItemId++) {
            var viewItem = view[viewItemId];
            filteredRows.push(viewItem);
          }
          targetPage++;
          if (targetPage <= totalPages) {
            PageTraverser(dataSource, targetPage, totalPages, filters, completionFunction);
          } else {
            completionFunction();
          }
        });
      }
```

Working example here: http://dojo.telerik.com/@JBoman32768/Ucudi

Answer (score 1):

Here is how we are currently doing it, although there are multiple options:

```
var myData = new kendo.data.Query(dataSource.data()).filter(dataSource.filter()).data;
```

Your simply calling a new Query and applying the current filter that the grid has applied, which will return the exact same results as the grid.

Comment: Create one. Thanks!

Comment: This seems to return the same data as the grid.  For instance, I have 300 rows and they're shown in pages of 10.  When I make my new `myData` using your example, I can only get to the first 10 rows of data.  The problem is that i need to be able to get to all rows with the current filter.